# Physical address-logical address

Tags: operating-system

How to calculate the physical address for the following logical addresses:

a)0,430

b)1,10.

The segments are:

segments:0,1,3,4

base:219;2300;1327;1952

length:600;14;580;96.

I have an exam in 2 days and I do not understand how to solve this problem.I want a solution just for one logical address to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Segment          Starting Address          Ending Address
2. 0                219                       819
3. 1                2300                      2314
4. 3                1327                      1907
5. 4                1952                      2048

Now you can compare a and b from above table.

a. Segment 0, Logical Address is 430 - So physical address becomes - 219+430 = 649
b. Segment 1, Logical Addres is 10 - So physical address becomes - 2300+10 = 2310.
Hope you understand.

P.S. :- People here will not like homework or without self search questions to be posted.